# How to get step-wise validation loss curve over all epochs in PyTorch Lightning

Tags: pytorch-lightning

When logging my validation loss inside `validation_step()` in PyTorch Lighnting like this:

```
def validation_step(self, batch: Tuple[Tensor, Tensor], _batch_index: int) -> None:
    inputs_batch, labels_batch = batch

    outputs_batch = self(inputs_batch)
    loss = self.criterion(outputs_batch, labels_batch)

    self.log('loss (valid)', loss.item())
```

Then, I get an epoch-wise loss curve:

[image]

If I want the step-wise loss curve I can set `on_step=True`:

```
def validation_step(self, batch: Tuple[Tensor, Tensor], _batch_index: int) -> None:
    inputs_batch, labels_batch = batch

    outputs_batch = self(inputs_batch)
    loss = self.criterion(outputs_batch, labels_batch)

    self.log('loss', loss.item(), on_step=True)
```

This results in step-wise loss curves for each epoch:

[image]

**How can I get a single graph over all epochs instead?** When running my training for thousands of epochs this gets messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have done something wrong when init your logger. Is it defined as the following:

```
logger = TensorBoardLogger("tb_logs", name="my_model")
```

Note that `on_step` will modify your tag which is one cause why they show up as separate images.

Instead of using on_step you can use:

```
self.logger.experiment.add_scalar('name',metric)
```

If you want the plots x axis to show number of epochs instead of steps you can place the logger within `validation_epoch_end(self, outputs)`.

```
def validation_epoch_end(self, outputs):
   avg_loss = torch.stack([x["val_loss"] for x in outputs]).mean()
   self.logger.experiment.add_scalar('loss',avg_loss, self.current_epoch)
```

Comment: I didn't initialize my logger. AFAIK the default logger is guaranteed to be a TensorBoard logger. But I guess bypassing `self.log()` and accessing the logger directly via `self.logger.experiment` is a solution. Too bad `self.log()` is so limited.

Comment: self.log() provides simple access to log data over all frameworks but if we access experiment we can get each unique feature supported by our framework (e.i tensorboard). I would recommend to init the logger. Also check the API. Here is the link since pytorch-lightning interface is quite bad. https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_references.html?highlight=api

Comment: In my experience, one needs to use `self.logger.experiment.add_scalars()` (with an `s`) to get the desired behavior. `add_scalar()` (without an `s`) does not plot the x-values as expected.